# Storing results of multiple linq queries in IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I was wondering if it was possible to store the results of multiple linq queries in a single `IQueryable` statement?

I have a query which I use in a foreach:

```
//Where OnDemandHistory is the table
IOrderedQueryable<OnDemandHistory> A; 

foreach (int id in machineID)
{
    A = OnDemandHistory.Where(c => c.MachineID == id).OrderByDescending(c => c.ODHisDate);
    // I want to Order all results before writing to the table
    foreach(var entry in A)
    {         
      // I add to a table based on all entries found in A
    }
}
```

I am trying to get all entries where the machine ID match. The no. of MachineID's is varying (based on the user).

I was wondering if I can do a `OrderByDescending` after I have stored all the results from the query but before adding to the table.

I know due to the inner `foreach` loop that it won't happen, however when I try to do this:

```
foreach (int id in machineID)
{
    A = OnDemandHistory.Where(c => c.MachineID == id).OrderByDescending(c => c.ODHisDate);
    // I want to Order all results before writing to the table       
}

foreach(var entry in A)
{         
    // I add to a table based on all entries found in A
}
```

I get a local variable A uninitialized error,

How would I go about solving this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because as the final result of your first query produces only the result of the last value of `machineID` this may result in either a null result or an uninitialisedvalue of A, so A needs to be initialised. Also, I suspect A could be a simple list.

You need something like:

```
A = new List<OnDemandHistory>();
foreach (int id in machineID)
{
    A.AddRange(OnDemandHistory
     .Where(c => c.MachineID == id).OrderByDescending(c => c.ODHisDate).ToList());          
}
// order A here
```

Then run your second loop having checked that A has rows. However, I suspect there are smarter ways in LINQ of concatenating the `machineID` part of the query as a single LINQ statement.

Comment: I tried your code, it still produces the same results as I had,
I added `A.OrderByDescending(c => c.ODHisDate);`
And still nothing

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and examining the contents of A with a breakpoint before you start the second loop. Some sample data plus the definition of `OnDemandHistory` would help.

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea, which helped me solve my problem. I looked at the `OnDemandHistory` table itself and ran a similar query, I sorted by another field rather than MachineID,
Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 3):

You can do it much simpler by using the `Contains` statement:

```
var result = OnDemandHistory.Where(c => machineID.Contains(c.MachineID))
                            .OrderByDescending(c => c.ODHisDate);
```

Comment: I tried this method earlier, I got a conversion error "Cannot convert from int? to int"

Comment: Then, depending on what `OnDemandHistory` actually is, you can use `c.MachineID.GetValueOrDefault()` or `c.MachineID.Value`, assuming that `machineID` doesn't contain 0.